# gradle - how to access file remotely

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

A few months ago i read the gradle manual and i thought i was able to reference a file remotely.  So hosted with http. For example here is a sample json file hosted somewhere on the internet :

http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json

so a simple task i want to achieve is to read this file in gradle and print out the output as a proof of concept.

Thus, in my build.gradle file i put the following:

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->

        FileCollection collection = files('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json')
        if (!collection.isEmpty()) {
            File file = collection.getSingleFile();
            println 'this is the file'+ file.text;
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting the following error:

Error:(51, 0) Cannot convert URL 'http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json' to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read only [file URL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) with `File` like `file:/path/to/file`

To download a text file and read it line by line, you can convert it to an URL object and read it with a `Reader` :

```
def line
'http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json'.toURL().withReader { reader ->
    while (line = reader.readLine()) {
        println line
    }
}
```